# " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null"? whats wrong with document.getElementById('tmessage').innerHTML= message;?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    

<head>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Form Validations">
        <title>Form Validations</title>
        <script>
           function checkFormData(){
            // var message = "";
             //Access the Text box content
             var tname = document.getElementById('txt_name').value;
             var temail = document.getElementById('txt_email').value;
             var tage = document.getElementById('txt_age').value;
     
             //Access the radio button values
             var tgender1 = document.getElementById('radio1').checked;
             var tgender2 = document.getElementById('radio2').checked;
     
             //Access Checkbox
             var tchkbox = document.getElementById('chkbox').checked;
             var message="";
             message += "Name: " + tname + "<br>";
             message += "Email: " + temail + "<br>";
             message += "Age: " + tage + "<br>";
             message += "Male: " + tgender1 + "<br>";
             message += "Female: " + tgender2 + "<br>";
             message += "Agreed: " + tchkbox + "<br>";
            // alert(message);
            
            document.getElementById('tmessage').innerHTML= message; //error 
       
         }
         </script>

    </head>
        

    <body>
            
                <p id="tmesssage"></p>
                 
                <h1>Form Validations</h1>
                
                <form action="https://phpbootcamp.com" method="get">
                    Name: <input type="text" name="tname" id="txt_name"/><br><br>
                    Email: <input type="text" name="temail" id="txt_email"/><br><br>
                    Age: <input type="text" name="tage" id="txt_age"><br><br>
                
            
                Male <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio1" checked>
                Female <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio2"><br><br>
            
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="chkbox"/> Agree to our Terms <br> <br>
            
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkFormData();">
            </form>
            
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no element with `tmessage` as id?

Comment: There is an extra "s" in the element id value (in the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

In your Code the id of `p` tag is `tmesssage` whereas in the below line :

`document.getElementById('tmessage').innerHTML= message;`

the id is `tmessage` where one s is missing.

Once you make both the id's the same your error will disappear.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: This is a typo. Please don’t answer questions that were caused by typos. This will help nobody in the future. Once you have the necessary reputation you can flag or vote to close such questions with the appropriate reasons. Focus on good questions instead.